# "It's of allergic reason" Vs. "It's from allergic reason"

Tags: prepositions

> The patient **has allergic inflammation of the skin**, thus he shouldn't get antibiotics which are for infection, treating the presence of bacteria.

Now I'm going to explain this phrase:

> Here it's written that this inflammation is **of** allergic.

Or should I say:

> Here it's written that this inflammation  **from** allergic.

What is correct to choose?

Comment: Neither is correct.  "Allergic" is an adjective.  You want the noun form, *allergy*.  The inflammation is *from* or *due to* or *caused by* an allergy.

Comment: Exactly what @stangdon said. You could use the adjective from if you said something like: "This inflammation seems to be an allergic reaction."

Comment: @stangdon, simply from my own experience, I'd end up using *because of allergies*. I usually see the singular form used when describing a specific allergy (e.g. `he has a wheat allergy`) and the plural form used when describing the immune disorder as a concept.

Comment: Thank you all. But supposing that I wrote allergy instead of allergic. What preposition would you chose?

Comment: If you use **allergy**, then you need both a preposition *and* an article: "...this inflammation is **from an** allergy."

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer

> **Here it's written that this inflammation is an allergic one.**

### Explanation

The point that you're paraphrasing is that "inflammation" is "allergic".

So, because

> **(adjective) (noun) -> (noun) (be verb) (adjective)**

then

> **allergic reaction -> reaction is allergic**

So, a concise way to say this is

> Here it's written that this inflammation is allergic.

However, this might imply to some listeners that:

> Here it's written that this inflammation is allergic (to something).

So, to clarify that, we try another option. We know inflammation is an inflammation, and inflammation is also allergic, so:

> Here it's written that this inflammation is an allergic inflammation.

And, to be more concise:

> **Here it's written that this inflammation is an allergic one.**

Comment: Even though you modified this sentence ***Here it's written that this inflammation is allergic.*** into another one, is it a correct sentence and did you modify it only to prevent a little confusion for some listeners?

Comment: Exactly, yes and yes. "Here it's written that this inflammation is allergic" is correct, but to be even clearer (and admittedly borderline verbose to some listeners/readers),  I modified it to the final sentence.

Comment: Thank you for the kind reply. It helps a lot. Have a great day.